# combine matching tuples elements with unique elements of other tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension

I would like to make a new list of tuples from the tuples that match other tuples on their first element.  When the tuples match with another tuple on their first element I would also like to add the third element to the matching tuple.

Example of the data (tuples have 3 strings):

```
unique_3 = [(apple, banana, fruit),
           (apple, banana, dessert),
           (eggplant, fig, plant),
           (eggplant, fig, purple),
           (iris, jaguar, horse)]
```

The output I am looking for:

```
new_list =[(apple, banana, [fruit, dessert]), 
           (eggplant, fig, [plant, purple]),
           (iris, jaguar, horse)]
```

I only really need to match on the first element of the tuple.  So I have tried this:

```
new_list= [next(i for i, v in enumerate(unique_3) if v[0] == any(v[0]))]
```

which returns StopIteration without results, so I haven't gotten very far with building the new_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group the items based on the first element of each tuple,

```
from itertools import groupby

unique_sorted = sorted(unique_3, key = lambda x: x[0])

group_list = []
for key, group in groupby(unique_sorted, lambda x: x[0]):
        group_list.append(list(group))

new_list = [(x[0][0], x[0][1], [y[-1] for y in x]) for x in group_list]
```

At each `for` iteration, `groupby` returns groups of elements `group` with the same first tuple element, `key`. The elements have to be consecutive in order to be group, hence the original list is sorted in the first step based on the first value in each tuple.